# Inner join with this condition: when the value in the first table is "ALL", it is joined with all the values in second table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to join 2 tables on multiple values.

When a value in the first table is "ALL", it should join on all the values in the second table. If it is any other value, it should join normally.

I needed to join on 5 different columns, 4 of which might have the value "ALL" (Column1, Column2, Column3 and Column4), so I wrote the following query made of 16 part queries.

It works, but I assume there must be a better way to do this. How could I optimise it?

[Example image join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYdUE.png)

[Example image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6vtt.png)

```
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP     
INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                         AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                         AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                         AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                         AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
                                             AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
                                             AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
                                             AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
                                             AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
                                             AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
                                             AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
                                             AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
                                             AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
                                             AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
                                             AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
                                             AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
                                             AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
                                             AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
                                             AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
                                             AND PP.Column1 = MV.Column1
                                             AND PP.Column2 = MV.Column2
                                             AND PP.Column3 = MV.Column3
                                             AND PP.Column4 = MV.Column4
WHERE MV.Column1 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 != 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 != 'ALL'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] AS PP
     INNER JOIN [Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] AS MV ON PP.Column5 = MV.Column5
WHERE MV.Column1 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column2 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column3 = 'ALL'
  AND MV.Column4 = 'ALL';
```

Comment: `OR Column5 = 'All'`?

Comment: @Larnu please write an answer before OP's code spreads even more!

Comment: Please use some indentation in your sql query, this is just to hard to read

Comment: White space is a wonderful thing; I can't read that SQL at all. Also, there's no way that is your full statement, it starts with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Well, the OP's code only grew by 200 lines, @GeorgeMenoutis. So if it increases in size again (at the same rate) it'll be about 8500 lines long. ;)

Comment: Sorry :) for some reason when i post the query, the beginning gets cut out. I'm trying to fix it

Comment: That query looks way over complicated now it's in a format people can read. I think Sample data and expected results may be a far better start here.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, good idea, i'll make some sample data

Comment: Images of data aren't helpful @Daiva. Pot sample data as **formatted** `text` or as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: In this case Colmn5 did not have the "ALL" values. If it did, i'd have to make a cross join and an additional "Where" clause

Answer (score 4):

I applied the suggestion of Mahesh and the final query looks like this:

```
select * from [Temporaer-Prozessplan-Resultat] as PP        
inner join      
[Mapping-Lean-Vergaben] as MV       
on      
    PP.column5=MV.column5   

where   1= case when MV.column1 ='ALL' then 1 
              when PP.column1=MV.column1 then 1
          else 0
          end
and
        2= case when MV.column2  ='ALL' then 2 
              when PP.column2 =MV.column2  then 2
          else 0
          end

and
        3= case when MV.column3  ='ALL' then 3 
              when PP.column3 =MV.column3  then 3
          else 0
          end

and
        4= case when MV.column4 ='ALL' then 4 
              when PP.column4=MV.column4 then 4
          else 0
          end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include filter as mentioned below

```
Where 1= case when columnName ='ALL' then 1 
              when columnFrom_oneTable = columnFrom_OtherTable then 1
          else 0
          end
```

Comment: Boolean logic (`AND`/`OR`) would be better here than a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE`. Expressions like these make the query non-SARGable; which will have (severe) performance impacts.

Comment: You're welcome, can you mark it as helpful if it worked.

Comment: Apparently i don't have enough "reputation" to upvote someone :( sorry...